# Modify the default WorkManager in WebSphere 7 using a wsadmin script

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin, workmanagers

I want to raise the maximum number of threads in the default work manager's thread pool using a wsadmin (Jython) script.  What is the best approach?

I can't seem to find documentation of a fine-grained control that would let me modify just this property.  The closest I can find to what I want is [AdminTask.applyConfigProperties](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/txml_config_prop_workmgrinfo_j2eeres.html), which requires passing a file.  The documentation explains that if you want to modify an existing property, you must extract the existing properties file, edit it in an editor, and then pass the edited file to applyConfigProperties.

I want to avoid the manual step of extracting the existing properties file and editing it.  The scripts needs to run completely unattended.  In fact, I'd prefer to not use a file at all, but just set the property to a value directly in the script.

Something like the following pseudo-code:

```
defaultwmId = AdminConfig.getid("wm/default")
AdminTask.setProperty(defaultwmId, ['-propertyName', maxThreads, '-propertyValue', 20])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following represents a fairly simplistic `wsadmin` approach to updating the max threads on the default work managers:

```
workManagers = AdminConfig.getid("/WorkManagerInfo:DefaultWorkManager/").splitlines()
for workManager in workManagers :
  AdminConfig.modify(workManager, '[[maxThreads "20"]]')
AdminConfig.save()
```

Note that the first line will retrieve all of the default work managers across *all scopes*, so if you want to only choose one (for example, if you only one to modify a particular application server or cluster's work manager properties), you will need to refine the containment path further. Also, you may need to synchronize the nodes and restart the modified servers in order for the property to be applied at runtime.

More information on the use of the `AdminConfig` scripting object can be found in the WAS InfoCenter:
  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_adminconfig1.html